# Python: Keep changes on a variable made within a function

Tags: python, function, variables

I have a question on a fairly simple task in python, however, I didn't manage to find a solution. I would like to assign a new value to an already existing variable in python. However, the changes I am doing to the variable within the function don't stick to the variable.

Here is a simplified example of my problem:

```
y = 1
x = None

def test(var):

    var = y

    return var 


test(x)
print(x)
```

The print simply returns none. So the changes I have done to the variable within the function are non permanent.

How can I make the changes on the input-variable of the function permanent?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: write `x = test(x)`.. instad of `test(x)`.

Comment: You only ever change the ``var`` variable, what else do you expect to change?

Comment: You did not change the variable, you created a new one with the same name.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean `x = test(x)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of passing variables to functions by value. By default, when you pass a variable to a function in Python, it is passed by value.

What it means is, that a new variable with a new scope is created with the same value of `x`. So, any change that happens to the new `x` is not reflected to the `x` outside the function's scope.

If you want to get the value from the function back, you can use the return statement (as you have used). `return` returns the value back from the function. However, in your example there is no variable to receive it. Hence, it is lost.

You would have to call the function as `x = test(x)`. This ensures that `x` receives the value back from the function.

Comment: Python has only one type of variable, and they are always passed the same way.

Comment: Ahh. I always get confused between Python and C. Lemme fix that. :P

Answer (score 7):

Variables in Python are just names which *refer* to objects. In an expression, the name is a stand-in for the actual object. Saying `test(x)` means "pass the object referred to by `x` into `test`". It does not mean "pass the symbol `x` into `test`".

In addition, re-assigning a name only changes what object *that name* refers to. It affects neither the object nor any of its aliases.

In short, the name `var` you modify inside `test` has no relation to `x` at all.

---

The preferred way to have a function change something is by reassigning the result:

```
x = 2
def change(var):
    return var * 2

x = change(x)  # x now refers to 4 instead of 2
print(x)
```

---

If you want to change a name outside a function, you can use the [`nonlocal` and `global` keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names):

```
x = 2
def change_x():
    global x
    x = x * 2

change_x()  # x now refers to 4 instead of 2
print(x)
```

While this can make some trivial problems easy to solve, it is generally a bad idea for larger programs. Using global variables means one can no longer use the function in isolation; results may depend on how often and in what order such a function is called.

---

If you have some self-contained group of values and means to modify them, a class can be used to describe this:

```
class XY:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    def swap(self):
        self.x, self.y = self.y, self.x

my_values = XY(None, 1)
print(my_values.x, my_values.y)
my_values.swap()
print(my_values.x, my_values.y)
```

In contrast to `global` variables, you can create as many isolated instances of classes as needed. Each instance can be worked on in isolation, without affecting the others.

---

You can also use mutable values to make changes visible to the outside. Instead of changing the name, you modify the value.

```
x = [2]  # x is a mutable list, containing the value 2 at the moment
def change(var):
    var[0] = 4  # change leading element of argument

change(x)  # x now contains 4 instead of 2
print(x)
```

Comment: Mutable list is a great solution, thanks!