# How to add a string to another from a function

Tags: python, string, function

I have a string called `x` and function called `my_func`. I want to add a string to the `x`, from `my_func`. I tried below code but it returns an error and says `"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment"`. How can I fix it?

```py
x = ""
def my_func():
    x += "Hello World"
my_func()
print(x)
```

Comment: You don't seem to call the function. If you did you'd get an UnboundLocalError exception. Read about local and global variables in the documentation

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249829/python-keep-changes-on-a-variable-made-within-a-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `x` is local, it has to be inside the function for it to work:

```
x = ""
def my_func(x):
    x += "Hello World"
    return x
x = my_func(x)
x = my_func(x)
print(x)
```

gives:

```
Hello WorldHello World
```

The trick is to reassign x.

Comment: you should be returning x, `return x` instead of print. Still, your answer looks good :)

Comment: @DialFrost OP wants to add (append) a string to *x*. This code does not do that. Add *print(x)* after the call to *my_func* and you'll see that nothing's happened to it

Comment: @DialFrost That still won't modify the global variable *x*. Remember that strings are passed by value (not by reference)

Comment: @DialFrost not really what i want to. Your code is like an illusion, it returns what i want to but it doesn't append it to the variable x so i can't repeat it

Comment: @Zienz: You only need to do: `x = my_func(x)` to make the modification.

Comment: Yes, I see. Unfortunately I can't up vote you again. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know it should be inside the function but if i do that, it wouldn't work as i want it to. Because i am recalling the func multiple times and need it to keep adding strings to x variable. For example, i need belove code to output "Hello worldHello world" instead of "Hello world". Btw i know my english is bad, sorry about that

```
def my_func():
    my_func.x = ""
    my_func.x += "Hello world"
my_func()
my_func()
print(my_func.x)
```

Comment: You would simply replace many `my_func()` with many `x = my_func(x)`.